# Is there any limit on size of the data that is passed to post method in jersy framework?

Tags: java, json, ajax

I am calling the Java Jersy post method from ajax call with json data. But post method is not getting the complete data, is there any limitation on the size of the data that is passed.

Comment: If there's an issue with hitting the limit on server side the entire request would be rejected. If you're seeing a partial request, that is what you're client sends

Answer (score 0):

`maxPostSize` attribute is used to define the max size of the POST.

here is the documented limit:

> The maximum size in bytes of the POST which will be handled by the container FORM URL parameter parsing. The limit can be disabled by setting this attribute to a value less than or equal to 0. If not specified, this attribute is set to 2097152 (2 megabytes).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But i tried this already even then it isn't working.